# lumen - how to return updated data in json format?

Tags: laravel, lumen

Is there any way to return updated data in laravel lumen framework ? Currently I have to do like this -

```
$where = array('id' =>$id, 'verification_code' =>$verificationCode);
Driver::where($where)->update(array('verified_status' => 1));

$verificationcode = Driver::where($where)->select('verified_status')->get();
```

Is there any other way to fetch data after update in single query?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the update model

```
$model = Model::where($where) -> first();
$model -> verified_status=  1;
$model -> save();
return $model;
```

Hope this help.